# Automapper: assign id from null one-to-one property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapper

I am trying to map one to one classes by using NHibernate, AutoMapper and Fluent but it is not working for me. I get this error **attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property: Person**

Here are my non-model classes:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int personId;
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public int state;
    public string emailAddress;
    public User user;
}

public partial class User
{
public string Username {get; set;}
public string Password {get; set;}
public int UseLoginType {get; set}
}
```

Models: (I have removed unnecessary properties for simplicity)

```
public class Person
{
public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
public virtual string emailAddress; { get; set; }
public virtual int state; { get; set; }
public virtual User User { get; protected set; }
}

public class User {
 protected User() { }
 public User(Person person)
 {
   Person = Person;
 }
public virtual string Username { get; set; }
public virtual string Password { get; set; }
public virtual int? UseLoginType { get; set; }
public virtual Person Person { get; protected set; }
}
```

And here is fluent mapping of Person and User:

```
public PersonMap()
        {
            SetEntityProperties("Persons", "Person_ID");
            Map(x => x.FirstName);
            Map(x => x.LastName);
            Map(x => x.State).CustomType(typeof(Int32));
            HasOne(x => x.User).Cascade.All();
}

public UserMap()
        {
            Table("expense_Users");

            Id(x => x.Id, "fkPersonId").GeneratedBy.Foreign("Person");
            Map(x => x.Username);
            Map(x => x.Password);
            Map(x => x.UseLoginType);
            HasOne(x => x.Person).Constrained().ForeignKey();
        }
```

And this is how I create mapping and trying to map information:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Models.Person>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<User, Models.User>();

foreach (var item in templateData.Persons)
{
save<Models.Person>(item);
}

private object save<TModel>(object templateObject)
{
var dbModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TModel>(templateObject);
return repository.Save<object>(dbModel);
}
```

Can someone tell me how can I populate the Person object? Can anyone put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem myself. There could be other ways to solve this problem but here is my approach.

I told the AutoMapper while creating the mapping that ignore the User property(which is an instance of User model) when it maps the Person information like this;

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Models.Person>()
 .ForMember(x => x.User, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

and then I saved the Person and User information separately.

Since both Person and User have one to one relation and its User table who holds the Person primary key as a foreign key in database. So to solve this with Nhibernate and AutoMapping I used the AutoMapper `Custom Resolver` to resolve the reference of Person while saving the User information. Below code will clear this to you.

```
 AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<User, Models.User>()
       .ForMember(x => x.Person, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new personResolver(loadRepository)).FromMember(x => x.PersonId));

public class personResolver : ValueResolver<int, Models.Person>
    {
        private DatabaseLoadRepository loadRepository;
        public personResolver(DatabaseLoadRepository repo)
        {
            this.loadRepository = repo;
        }
        protected override Models.Person ResolveCore(int personId)
        {
            return loadRepository.FindOne<Models.Person>(x => x.Id == personId);
        }
    }
```

I hope this answer will help others